# Use stack or heap for MPI program variables

Tags: c, mpi, heap-memory, stack-memory

I recently started working with Intel MPI for parallelizing  a very simple flow solver. I'm wondering whether I should use the stack for storing my variables (i.e. use `datatype name[size];` for declaration) or the heap (i.e. use `datatype *name = (datatype *)malloc(size*sizeof(datatype));`).

First I used malloc, because I split up the flow field into `n` parts, where `n` is the number of processes that were created and I thought it would be nice to use the same code for all values of n. That means the size of my arrays is first known at runtime. Therefore I obviously need dynamic memory allocation. So far so good.

But that made the whole program very slow, due to the dynamic allocation. It was even slower then solving in serial.

I altered my program and used array declaration instead and got the expected speed up. But now my program cannot adjust to different starting conditions (e.g. number of processes, size of flow field, number of gridpoints,...).

Can anybody give advise what the common practise is to tackle this dilemma? There are obviously a lot of flow solvers in the world that have awesome performance AND can adjust to starting conditions.

Thanks a lot!

EDIT: I tried to simplify my code (it's no MWE though):

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int rank, numProcs, start, length, left, right;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numProcs);

    if (rank==0)
    {
        split_and_send_domain(&start, &length, &left, &right, numProcs);                                                                            

        // allocate memory for arrays like velocity, temperature,...
        double x1[length]; // double *x1=(double *)malloc(length*sizeof(double));
        double x2[length]; // double *x2=(double *)malloc(length*sizeof(double));
        ...
        double xn[length]; // double *xn=(double *)malloc(length*sizeof(double));

        // initialize variables like local residual, global residual, iteration step,...
        int res = 1, resGlob=1; iter=0,...;
        int keepOn = 1;

        setupCalculation(start, length, left, right, x1, x2, ...); // initializes the arrays

        MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

        while (keepOn){
            iter++;
            pass_boundaries(left, right, length, utilde, rank);
            do_calculation(length, x1, x2, ...);
            calc_own_residual(length, x1, x2, ...);         
            calc_glob_residual(&resGlob, res);

            if (iter>=maxiter || resGlob<1e-8)  keepOn = 0;

            MPI_Bcast(&keepOn, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        }

        /* gather results & do some final calculations & output*/
    }
    else
    {
        receive_domain(&start, &length, &left, &right);                                                                         

        // allocate memory for arrays like velocity, temperature,...
        double x1[length]; // double *x1=(double *)malloc(length*sizeof(double));
        double x2[length]; // double *x2=(double *)malloc(length*sizeof(double));
        ...
        double xn[length]; // double *xn=(double *)malloc(length*sizeof(double));

        // initialize variables like residual, iteration step,...
        int res = 1;
        int keepOn = 1;

        setupCalculation(start, length, left, right, x1, x2, ...); // initializes the arrays

        MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

        while (keepOn){
            pass_boundaries(left, right, length, utilde, rank);
            do_calculation(length, x1, x2, ...);
            calc_own_residual(length, x1, x2, ...);
            calc_glob_residual(&resGlob, res);

            MPI_Bcast(&keepOn, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        }
    }

    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

When using the dynamic allocation `int length` is additionally calculated at the beginning, else it is set as global const variable.

Comment: Without code is quite impossible to help you....

Comment: Dynamic allocation isn't that slow. The real problem is likely that you're doing a lot of dynamic allocations. Perhaps you're solving iteratively, and reallocate on each iteration?

Comment: You're right, it's an iterative solver. I allocate the memory once, before starting the iteration. During iteration I just read and write the array elements - no reallocation.

Comment: You're certain that if you change those arrays to be dynamically allocated, the program runs significantly slower? That seems ... unusual. How large is the speed difference? How big are those arrays, and how many of them are there? It would be useful to know if the speed difference is in the actual calculation, or in the allocation (although that would be pretty odd).

Comment: The difference is huge. About factor 15. The arrays have up to 15,000 elements and there are 5 of them, so nothing serious. I think the difference cannot come from the calculation itself as the serial code and the 'static' code do the same calculation work faster.

Comment: ..so I don't see any `free()`s?

Comment: It's a long shot, but potentially the compiler can do some clever optimisations when it knows the sizes at compile time. You could set length to a global const *and* use dynamic allocation to check this experimentally ...

Comment: I removed the `free()`s in this example, I have them in my real code

Comment: I solved it for me. And the solution is embarrassing. When I cloned my serial-code project to write the MPI-code, Visual Studio reset the project properties to use the Visual C compiler, instead of the Intel compiler. It seems as if the Visual C compiler doesn't work very well with Intel MPI (maybe isn't supposed to do). I changed to Intel compiler and now everything is working as it should. Thanks for your efforts guys!